# Selecting a subset of a dataframe works on its own, but does not work when part of a function

Tags: python, pandas, function

I have a dataframe with a column named 'time'. This code works just fine to remove all rows that do not equal 9am.

```
starttime = '09:00:00'
df = df.loc[df['time'] == starttime]
```

However, doing this as part of a function does not work at all. What am I missing?

```
def xyz(df,starttime):
  
    df = df.loc[df['time'] == starttime]

xyz(df,'09:00:00')
```

Comment: Re-assign the same named global data frame to the return value of function.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
def xyz(df, starttime):
    return df[df['time'] == starttime]

df = xyz(df, '09:00:00')
```

For in place modification:

```
def xyz(df, starttime):
    mask = df['time'] == starttime
    df.drop(df[~mask].index, inplace=True)

xyz(df, '09:00:00')
```